# how to change image name while uploading into folder in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

i am implementing a application in coldfusion in whis i have to store image with user defined name not actual name, i am able to store image into folder with actual name but not with user defined name ,i have to upload image into folder named "user_images", how can i change actual name with user defined name.
it will be better if any one provide code.

thanks
Yugal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a specific file name when you upload the file using the cffile tag.  Whatever filename you use in the destination attribute will be used to save the file.

Comment: Note that the destination attribute is intended to be a directory name and not a destination filename according to the docs. However, use of a file name does work but be careful as there was a particular version of CF (7.0.1 I believe) where this undocumented functionality broke. It was however sorted out with a hotfix.

Comment: Additionally, you might want to play it save and use the nameconflict="makeunique" then use CFFILE again to rename File.ServerFile to your user defined filename.

Comment: very true, good point Steve.  You could use the info returned from CFFILE to rename the file if you want to be 100% in compliance with CF's documentation.